# Как перейти к следующему input'у при заполнении текущего?

Tags: html, javascript

Форма, много инпутов, с определенной максимальной длинной. Как при заполнении отдого инпута (допустим 10 из 10 знаков) сделать так, чтобы курсор автоматом перепрыгнул на следующий инпут? При этом, если следующий уже заполнен (с такими же правилами перехода) еще на следующий инпут, курсор не перескакивал?

**Добавлено.**

Не могу применить.

```
<td>
<input  type="text" maxlength="4" size="4" onkeyup="testJump(this)" style="width:80px;height:28px;font-size:20px;">
</td>

<input  type="text" maxlength="4" size="4" onkeyup="testJump(this);" style="width:80px;height:28px;font-size:20px;">
</td>

<td style="padding-left:5px;">
<input  type="text" maxlength="4" size="4" onkeyup="testJump(this);" style="width:80px;height:28px;font-size:20px;">
</td>

<td style="padding-left:5px;">
        <input  type="text" maxlength="4" size="4" onkeyup="testJump(this);" style="width:80px;height:28px;font-size:20px;">
</td>
```

Comment: понял)тут не расчитано под разные ячейки)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
<script>
function testJump(x){
    var ml = ~~x.getAttribute('maxlength');
    if(ml && x.value.length >= ml){
        do{
            x = x.nextSibling;
        }
        while(x && !(/text/.test(x.type)));
        if(x && /text/.test(x.type)){
            x.focus();
        }
    }
}
</script>

<div>
    <input type="text" onkeyup="testJump(this);" maxlength="5" size="5">
    <input type="text" onkeyup="testJump(this);" maxlength="4" size="4">
    <input type="text" onkeyup="testJump(this);" maxlength="7" size="7">
    <input type="text" onkeyup="testJump(this);" maxlength="5" size="5">
</div>
```

Функция работает только для элементов с `type="text"`. Можете переписать проверку условия  и способ навешивания `onkeyup` на элементы.