# Как сделать автоматический переход на следующий input?

Tags: forms, html, javascript, django

Например, есть форма с тремя input. В каждый нужно вводить 1 число. Как сделать, чтобы при вводе в первый инпут одного числа курсор сразу перескакивал на следующий?

Comment: Добавьте в список меток js :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если имеется в виду цифра, то

```
$('input').keyup(function(){
  if($(this).val().match(/^\d{1}$/)){
    $(this).next('input').focus();
  }else{
    $(this).val('');
  }
});
```

Если имеется в виду ЧИСЛО, то

```
$('input').keyup(function(e){
  var symbol = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
  if($(this).val().match(/^\d+$/) && !symbol.match(/^\d{1}$/)){
    $(this).val(parseInt($(this).val()));
    $(this).next('input').focus();
  }else{
    $(this).val('');
  }
});
```

Comment: Хм, а **`{1}`** не лишнее тут? Просто уточнение) `\d` и `\d{1}` эквивалентны же

Comment: Лишнее. Но это чтобы было понятнее, что мы выбираем ОДНУ цифру

Answer (score 1):

Схожий [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/24052/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-input-%D1%83-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE) уже был.