# Не переходит focus на следующий input

Tags: javascript, html, input, focus

html:

```
              <form id = "mainForm">
             <div id = "div1">
             <input type="text" name="input-1" id = "input1" value="" size="10px" onkeyup="testJump(this);" maxlength="5" >         
             <input type="text" name="input-2" id = "input2" value="" size="10px" onkeyup="testJump(this);" maxlength="5" > 
             <input type="text" name="input-3" id = "input3" value="" size="10px" onkeyup="testJump(this);" maxlength="5" > 
             <input type="text" name="input-4" id = "input4" value="" size="10px" onkeyup="testJump(this);" maxlength="5" >

       <select id="listColor">
                         <option value="green">
                                Зеленый
                            </option>
                            <option value="red">
                                Красный
                            </option>
                            <option value="blue">
                                Синий
                            </option>
                            <option value="yellow">
                                Желтый    
                            </option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div id  = "div2">
      <input type="reset" name="Очистка формы"></td>       
      <button id = "showButton" >Отобразить данные</button>
      <button id = "insertButton">Вставка текстового поля</button>
      </div>

</form>
```

функция для автоматического перехода фокуса:

```
                                 function testJump(x){
var ml = ~~x.getAttribute('maxlength');
if(ml && x.value.length >= ml){
    do{
        x = x.nextSibling;
    }
    while(x && !(/text/.test(x.type)));
    if(x && /text/.test(x.type)){
        x.focus();
    }
}
}
```

функция взята отсюда:[Как перейти к следующему input'у при заполнении текущего?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/24052/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-input%D1%83-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE)

Однако фокус не переходит

Comment: у меня на Chrome  54.0.2840.87m это работет прекрасно

Comment: не работает ни в Chrome ни в Opera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скрипт полностью рабочий. Его нужно только подключить к html странице следующим образом: 
Скопируй следующею строку и вставь между тэгами  и  в своем html документе.

```html
<script src = "ЗДЕСЬ ПИШИ ССЫЛКУ НА СВОЙ javascript ФАЙЛ СОДЕРЖАЩИЙ КОД" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Исправил несколько ошибок..все работает. Может ты скрипт забываешь подключить?

```
<form id="mainForm">
  <div id="div1">
    <input type="text" name="input-1" id="input1" value="" size="10px" onkeyup="testJump(this);" maxlength="5">
    <input type="text" name="input-2" id="input2" value="" size="10px" onkeyup="testJump(this);" maxlength="5">
    <input type="text" name="input-3" id="input3" value="" size="10px" onkeyup="testJump(this);" maxlength="5">
    <input type="text" name="input-4" id="input4" value="" size="10px" onkeyup="testJump(this);" maxlength="5">
    <select id="listColor">
      <option value="green">Зеленый</option>
      <option value="red">Красный</option>
      <option value="blue">Синий</option>
      <option value="yellow">Желтый</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div id="div2">
    <input type="reset" name="Очистка формы">
    <button id="showButton">Отобразить данные</button>
    <button id="insertButton">Вставка текстового поля</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Скрипт:

```
function testJump(x){
  var ml = x.getAttribute('maxlength');
  if(ml && x.value.length >= ml){
    do {
      x = x.nextSibling;
    }
    while(x && !(/text/.test(x.type)));
    if(x && /text/.test(x.type)){
      x.focus();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Все подключено, что же ты исправил?

Comment: да там мелочь..работает?

Comment: И тот и тот вариант работает, когда скрипт прописан в html файле, когда его вынести в js в виде одной из функций не работает

Comment: когда ты его выносишь в скрипт ты точно скрипт подключаешь..вот как я его тестировал у себя и все заработало: http://joxi.ru/E2p1kkJHBK0jJA.jpg

Comment: точно скрипт подключаю, потому что при нажатии на кнопки отрабатывают функции, которые в скрипте

Comment: понятно..тут в консоли смотреть нужно весь код((

Comment: если не решил проблему - пиши, с помощью тимвьювера попытаюсь помочь

Comment: проблема решена

Comment: отлично, удачи))